# MYSQL Query won't Total Column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns for id, source, sessions and date. I want to grab all sessions for the last 28 days grouped by date for a specific id. The code below works, but I get ungrouped results with each day having multiple rows with sessions for each source.

#### Actual Result

3/1 25
3/1 24
3/2 6
3/3 7

#### Desired Result

3/1 49
3/2 6
3/3 7

I thought changing sessions to Sum(sessions) would work but I keep getting the following error:

In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'myDB.traffic.date'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT date, sessions

FROM traffic

WHERE date > DATE_SUB((SELECT MAX(date) from traffic), INTERVAL 28 DAY)

and id = '206661358'
```

Comment: You need to GROUP BY date and select the sum

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You need to "aggregate" the results with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date, sum(sessions)
FROM traffic
WHERE date > DATE_SUB((SELECT MAX(date) from traffic), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
  AND id = '206661358'
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it. I also added "as sessions" after more research to keep the column name from changing to sum(sessions).